# scrollbar insde one onther scroll bar

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

**Hi to  all,**
i was making a slider where i want some thing like below image.

[more in details vise in a picture](http://s17.postimg.org/p1kienav3/slider.jpg)

actualy one of my slider slide got a scroll bar .where i want it as when the user first scroll the page first the slider scoller should scroll and then the slider scroller end ,the page scroller should work normaly.

i have no idea how to do it in jquery but seen those kind of effect in many sites.

please help me and thanks in advance

Comment: I may not have understood you correctly, but I would *not* like to be confronted with this as a user. Reason: If  I see two scroll bars, I'd think that I can scroll them, independently, whenever I want. (This is very much like the scroll bar I have right now in my browser, for scrolling this page up and down, and the scroll bar I have in this window where I'm typing this comment right now.)

Comment: thank for the comment laune. but actually after successfully make the effct i was thinking to remove(by hiding) the scroll bar inside the slider. so user want know there was actually a scroll-bar inside the slider.

Comment: IF you could name one or more of these "many sites" where it is working? - However: this isn't Java - it is javascript. Please edit the tags!

Comment: sry .it has to be javascript. anyway some one edited it .thansk for that."many  sites"in the sense it was actually i cannot found the websites now. pls try to help me from the description.

Comment: Sorry, too - but that's not clear from the description. Try to find a site.